# $\phi$-Measurable cover of a set

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\phi$ be an outer measure on $X$ and $\mu$ be the restriction of $\phi$ to the collection $\mathcal{M}$ of the measurable sets. Now if $E\subset X$ we will call a set $G$ a $\phi$-measurable cover of $E$ when $G\in\mathcal{M}, E\subset G$ and for every $A\in\mathcal{M}$ with $A\subset G\setminus E$ it is $\mu (A)=0$.
Now let $G\in\mathcal{M} , E\subset G,  \mu(G) =\phi(E)$. Prove that $G$ is a $\phi$-measurable cover of $E$. 
Now I've dealt with the case of $\mu(G)< \infty$ by noticing that $E\subset G\setminus A$ and using monotony. I would be able to deal with the case of $\mu(G)=\infty$, if $\mu$ was $\sigma$-finite, but there's no such hypothesis. How should I tackle the case of infinite measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'll answer to myself:
This situation can't be tackled; consider the measure space $(\mathbb{N}, \mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N}), \mu)$ where $\mu(A)=\infty$ when $A\neq\emptyset$ and $\mu(\emptyset)=0$. Now it is obvious that $\mu$ is not $\sigma$-finite and it is an outer measure on $\mathbb{N}$. Let $E=2\mathbb{N}$. Then $E\subset\mathbb{N}, \mathbb{N}\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ and $\mu(E)=\mu(\mathbb{N})$. But $\mathbb{N}$ is not a $\mu$-measurable cover of $E$, since $A=2\mathbb{N}+1 \subset \mathbb{N}\setminus E, A\in\mathcal{P}(\mathbb{N})$ but $\mu(A)\neq 0$.